# Yii2: change site language throughout the session

Tags: php, session, internationalization, yii2

I read in the guide that I should use `Yii::$app->language = 'da-DK'` to change language - but it doesn't remember it for the next request. Do I manually have to store the current language in a session variable when I change it?

If so, where do read the session variable and set `Yii::$app->language` in the subsequent requests?

Comment: There is great guide how to do this in the [Yii 2 Cookbook](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/i18n-selecting-application-language)

Answer (score 0):

You may also write `'language' => 'da-DK'` at config/web

Comment: Okay, but it needs to be handled dynamically so that when the user changes the language it of course is remembered through the rest of his visit. I clarified my question now.

Comment: maybe this is for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881976/yii2-set-global-language-value